# clients computers can't resolve windows server's DNS name to join to domain

Tags: dns, windows-7, windows-server-2012, lan

I have set up a Windows Server 2012 Standard edition at home for learning purposes with the IP **10.1.1.2/16**. I also have an ADSL wireless router which connects everything together and works as the DHCP server, with the IP **10.1.1.1/16**. The Server name is in **server_name.domain_name.org** format and netBIOS name is as **server_name**.

When I try to join a client win7 PC to the **domain_name.org** domain by searching the domain as **domain_name.org** it says unable to find domain and if I try using just **domain_name** it finds the domain but fails to connect after entering username/password by giving the error **Unable to resolve DNS name of the domain**

I put a static IP to the win7 client with the DNS settings as **primary:10.1.1.2 (server) & secondary: 10.1.1.2 (router)** with **default gateway: 10.1.1.1**. Then searched and tried connecting to **domain_name.org** it worked really fine.

My problem is, I don't want to use static IPs for my clients. I suspect the issue should be with my ADSL router which is the DHCP server for the LAN. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't say "at home" on Serverfault...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with static IPs. Your clients need to use the domain controller(s) for the domain as their DNS server(s). Your modem/router is likely setting itself as the DNS server. Change this setting there so that it gives your clients the proper DNS server as part of the DHCP configuration.

---

As, just as a side note: please read our faq. Home networking is off topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I set the DNS in my router as 10.1.1.1 (itself) and 10.1.1.2 (the server) before asking here, still the error exists unless DNS settings are manually configured at client's end.

I test this at home first before trying in the real environment, otherwise why would I ever have a server 2012 with a domain at home??? Only difference is im learning. Thanks

Comment: Setting your router's DNS is different than setting the DNS server that your router hands out to clients. The *only* DNS Servers that AD clients should use are DCs. If you read the [faq] you will see that everything at a home is off topic. If you'd like to ask why, that's what [meta] is for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful.. specially pointing me to Meta Server Fault :) Sorry and apologies for troubling you all with these minor matters.